# Code should be creating buoyancy, but game object sinks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to overcome a sinking force with code. The code checks for current water height (using a different namespace which is working) and over time the Game object sinks, very slowly. I need to overcome that sinking and not sure how to do it.

I have tried a while loop, an if statement, and I could not figure out how to reset the position if it dropped below a certain transform.position.y

```
public float noSink;

void Start ()
{
    // This checks for current point height and is tested and working.
    HydroformComponent[] compList = FindObjectsOfType( typeof(HydroformComponent)) as HydroformComponent[];
    if(compList[0] != null)
    {
        Water = compList[0];
        noSink += (transform.position.y + 2.5f) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if( Water == null ) return;

    float height = Water.GetHeightAtPoint( transform.position );
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, height, transform.position.z );

    // Trying to fix the slow sink here
    while (transform.position.y <= 0)
        transform.up = new Vector3(transform.position.x, noSink, transform.position.z);

}
```

Expecting the object to bob back up over `time.deltatime` when the game object reaches `transform.position.y <= 0`

It actually just keeps dropping the object below 0 with no correction.

Answer (score 1):

[`transform.up`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html) is a local upwards **direction**! By setting this value all you change is it's rotation **not position**.

I think you wanted to use `transform.position` instead.

---

Also `FixedUpdate` should only be used for stuff related to the Physics. Otherwise rather use `Update`.

---

Instead of looking for a hotfix or workarounds I in your place would rather try to find an answer to the question

**Why is it sinking in the first place?**

Of course I have no clue what your `HydroformComponent` and `GetHeightAtPosition` does ... But your line

```
noSink += (transform.position.y + 2.5f) * Time.deltaTime;
```

looks strange already.

Why do you multiply the current `y` position by `Time.deltaTime`?

Also why do you do this in `Start` at all where `Time.deltaTime` makes not much sense?

This value is used for avoiding frame dependency when doing movements frame wise. It makes little sense for setting an initial value once. It might even simply be `0` if this `Start` method is called during app start before the very first `Update` message.

---

I guess instead you should do something like

```
private void Start()
{
    // Since you only want the first found object anyway
    Water = FindObjectOfType<HydroformComponent>();
    if(water)
    {
        noSink = transform.position.y + 2.5;
    }
}
```

and then later

```
void Update()
{
    if(!Water) return;

    float height = Water.GetHeightAtPoint(transform.position);
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, height, transform.position.z);

    // Trying to fix the slow sink here
    if (transform.position.y <= 0)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, noSink, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Note however that now it will pop back up instead of slowly "wobbling". You could also simply limit the `y` position using e.g.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Max(height, noSink), transform.position.z);
```

Comment: Still sinks...... which stinks. I tried making your changes to my code without success. the transform position y is at -13 and falling still. It really doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: then it seems to me something else is controlling the position as well. Any rigidbody in play? Also it would help to see the implentation of `HydroformComponent`